# ListView does not refresh whereas attached list does (Flutter)

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to get familiar with flutter and I'm facing some weird case. I want to build a dynamic `ListView` where a `+` button allows to add elements. I wrote the following State code:

```
class MyWidgetListState extends State<MyWidgetList> {
  List<Widget> _objectList = <Widget>[
    new Text('test'),
    new Text('test')
  ];

  void _addOne() {
    setState(() {
      _objectList.add(new Text('test'));
    });
  }

  void _removeOne() {
    setState(() {
      _objectList.removeLast();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: _objectList
        ),
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
              iconSize: 36.0,
              tooltip: 'Remove',
              onPressed: _objectList.length > 2 ? _removeOne : null,
            ),
            new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.add_circle),
              iconSize: 36.0,
              tooltip: 'Add',
              onPressed: _addOne,
            )
          ],
        ),
        new Text(_objectList.length.toString())
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

My problem here is that the ListView is visually stuck with the 2 elements I initialized it with.

Internally the `_objectList` is well managed. For testing purpose I added a simple `Text` widget at the bottom that shows the size of the list. This one works fine when I click the Add/Remove buttons and it gets properly refreshed. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Flutter is based around immutable data. Meaning that if the reference to an object didn't change, the content didn't either.

The problem is, in your case you always send to `ListView` the same array, and instead mutate its content. But this leads to `ListView` assuming the list didn't change and therefore prevent useless render.

You can change your `setState` to keep that in mind :

```
setState(() {
  _objectList = List.from(_objectList)
    ..add(Text("foo"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and the explanation, it works fine now.

Comment: I'm implementing pagination so i'm adding a bunch of documents to the list.
Inside setstate(), 
 posts = List<Post>.from(posts)
        ..addAll(snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
          Post.fromDocument(doc);
        }).toList());

This is my code snippet, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I can't figure out what's wrong. Please help. and sorry for the weird-looking code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

**Another Solution!!**

Replace `ListView` with `ListView.builder`

**Code:**

```
    ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (ctx, item) {
              return _objectList[item];
            },
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: _objectList.length,
          ),
```

**Output:**

[image]