# Flutter remove item from List of maps read-only error

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I want to remove an item from my list in a `ListView.builder` but it's saying it's read only.

```
List<Map> entries = [{'date': '2019-08-10', 'data': 85.0}, {'date': '2019-08-14', 'data': 84.0}];

onPressed: () {
  removeItem(index);
}

void removeItem(index) {
  entries.removeAt(index);
}
```

`Another exception was thrown: Unsupported operation: read-only`

This does not work either:

```
onPressed: () {
  removeItem(date);
}

void removeItem(date) {
  entries.removeWhere((item) => item['date'] == date);
}
```

Comment: If you change `List<Map>` to something else say `List<int> entries = [1,2]`, do you still get the error?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad It seems not, no error if it's just a list of ints.

Answer (score 5):

I got the solution from this, [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51931017/update-ui-after-removing-items-from-list)

```
entries = List.from(entries)..removeAt("theIndexValue");
```