# Refreshing data after database operation in SQFlite

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I have a ListView that generates ListTiles after reading data from an SQFlite database. Each tile has an IconButton that allows user to delete that row. The delete operation works fine, but the ListView does not refresh and the items are still visible. How can I get the application to refresh data after the delete operation?

```
class TaskListState extends State<TaskList> {
  DBProvider dbProvider = new DBProvider();
  Future<List<Task>> tasks;

  @override
  void initState() {
    tasks = dbProvider.getAllTasks();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: tasks,
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasError){
          return Text("Data has error.");
        } else if (!snapshot.hasData){
          return Text("Wait please...");
        } else {
          return taskList(snapshot.data);
        }
      },
    );
  }


  Widget taskList(List<Task> tasks){
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: tasks.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        String _subtitle = tasks[index].date + " " + tasks[index].start + "-" + tasks[index].end;
        return Card(
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.face),
            title: Text(tasks[index].name),
            subtitle: Text(_subtitle),
            onTap: (){print("Tapped");},
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: (){
                dbProvider.delete(tasks[index].id);
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: here are some links to close or similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51931017/update-ui-after-removing-items-from-list

Comment: I've checked them out but I cannot do a setState call to refresh the data, it says Future<List<Task>> cannot be assigned to List<Task>