# flutter not rendering when color changes

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to flutter/dart. I have written an app that displays tiles in a GridView. Each tile is numbered and colored and is assigned an onTap handler. The onTap handler is to debugPrint the index of the tile and invoke setState(). setState() is expected to force the re-rendering of the GridView with the tapped tile displayed in Color.white.

When executed in debug mode, the display on the device is as expected. When a tile is tapped, the debugPrint message is displayed in the DEBUG CONSOLE, but the color of the tapped tile does not change to Color.white.

I have examined the tiles when they are regenerated (when a tile has been tapped). As expected, all of the untapped tiles are assigned their original tile colors. The tapped tile is assigned Color.white. But the change in tile color (i.e., the tapped tile color change from its original color to Color.white) appears not to be detected and the app does not redraw with one white tile.

The app code follows. Please advise what I am doing wrong.

```
// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types
// ignore_for_file: constant_identifier_names
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const List _normal_colors = [
  Colors.indigo,
  Colors.green,
  Colors.amber,
  Colors.orange,
  Colors.red,
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.cyan,
  Colors.yellow,
  Colors.purple,
]; // _normal_colors

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class Tiled_Surface extends StatefulWidget {
  Tiled_Surface({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override // Tiled_Surface
  Tiled_Surface_State createState() => Tiled_Surface_State();
}

class Tiled_Surface_State extends State<Tiled_Surface> {
  List<GridTile> _grid_tiles = <GridTile>[];
  int _tapped = -1;

  void on_tile_tapped(int index) {
    debugPrint("You tapped on item $index");
    setState(() {
      _tapped = index;
    });
  } // on_tile_tapped

  GridTile new_surface_tile(Color tile_color, int index) {
    GridTile tile = GridTile(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => on_tile_tapped(index),
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text (
              index.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24.0,
                color: _tapped == index ?
                           Colors.black :
                           Colors.white,),
            )
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: _tapped == index ?
                       Colors.white :
                       tile_color,
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  return (tile);
  } // new_surface_tile

  List<GridTile> surface_tiles(colors) {
    _grid_tiles.clear();
    for (int i = 0; (i < colors.length); i++) {
      _grid_tiles.add(new_surface_tile(colors[i], i));
    }
    return (_grid_tiles);
  } // surface_tiles

  @override // Tiled_Surface_State
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      childAspectRatio: 1.0,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
      children: surface_tiles(_normal_colors),
    );
  }
} // class Tiled_Surface_State

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget tiled_surface = Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Tiled_Surface(),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Tiled Surface Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Tiled Surface Demo'),
                       actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            tooltip: "Replay",
            icon: Icon(Icons.replay),
            onPressed: () {
// TODO       _reinitialize_tiles ( );
            },
          ),
        ] ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            tiled_surface,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This question differs from that of the recommended answer in that this deals with a private class of ListView while this question deals with a GridView.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListView does not refresh whereas attached list does (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51813435/listview-does-not-refresh-whereas-attached-list-does-flutter)

Comment: There is a difference between ListView and GridView. I cannot just add a GridTile. I tried adding _grid_tiles.clear(); to setState() to no avail.

Comment: The problem is the same though. You are keeping the same list instance as children. the `clear` call is the proof

Comment: Please advise how I change the code. This has been a distraction for the last 4 weeks. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51813435/listview-does-not-refresh-whereas-attached-list-does-flutter) this problem happens because you don't follow immutability principles.

The root of the problem lies in your `surface_tiles` method. Which instead of creating a new list, reuse the old one.

The fix is pretty straightforward:

```
List<GridTile> surface_tiles(colors) {
  _grid_tiles = List<Widget>();
  // push items to grid_tiles
```

instead of

```
List<GridTile> surface_tiles(colors) {
  _grid_tiles.clear()
  // push items to grid_tiles
```

Comment: thank you for your time and patience. Your suggestion worked. Only one problem, the line _grid_tiles = List<Widget>(); needed to be replaced by _grid_tiles = new List<GridTile>();  Thanks again.

Comment: Also, why are you using _grid_tiles at all? It seems pretty unnecessary and possibly even dangerous for it to be a member variable in this case...

Comment: @rmtmckenzie You raise an issue that makes me wonder if I even have the correct idea of how flutter/dart renders. Would you have any suggestions for a good book on the subject. I think I need to read it. Thanks

Comment: There's no books yet. The most you can have is medium/stackoverflow or flutter.io

Comment: @Gus Remi is right unfortunately. I'd advise reading the [technical overview](https://flutter.io/technical-overview/) from the flutter team and some of the tutorials in the flutter docs, and in particular the items under "More Details" in the left sidebar.