# Async periodic setState

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm trying to implement a function which will periodically add widget to my list (for example once at 2 seconds) and call `setState` to update the list, which I'm drawing.

I tried to just call `setState()`, it is working just once at all, I think `setState` just don't call functions. I tried to use even `While(true)` in function, but after `setState` it just breaks. Also I tried recursion, and it is also stops after one call.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>{

  List<Widget> currentMessages = [];

  Future<void> addText() async {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
      setState((){
        currentMessages.add(Text("It works?"));
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    addText();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: (currentMessages.isEmpty ? <Widget>[Container()]:currentMessages),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use `Timer.periodic` to call `addText`. Don't do it from `build`. Remember to override `dispose` so that you can cancel the timer.

Comment: Where I have to implement it? In build? Or in another async function?

Comment: you may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51813435/listview-does-not-refresh-whereas-attached-list-does-flutter/51813543#51813543

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
class _SOState extends State<SO> {
  List<Widget> currentMessages = [];

  Timer timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    const twoSec = const Duration(seconds: 2);
    timer = new Timer.periodic(twoSec, (Timer t) {
      setState(() {
        currentMessages.add(Text("It works?"));
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: currentMessages.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            if (currentMessages.length == 0) return Container();
            return currentMessages[index];
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Don't know why `ListView` doesn't update on changes for your code. So I used a `builder`.

Comment: If you don't want a builder, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51813435/listview-does-not-refresh-whereas-attached-list-does-flutter

Answer (score 1):

Override `initState` and `dispose` and create and cancel the timer in each respectively. For example:

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Timer t;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    t = Timer.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 1),
      (_) {
        setState(() {
          // do something here that will happen every second
        });
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    t?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it should work, but there is problem in ListView which described Doc so I used itemBuilder also