# Why is my Checkbox not updating when I pass a callback from a stateful widget to stateless widget?

Tags: flutter

Im trying to use Lift the State for my Checkbox and I know that by changing my TaskTile to a stateful widget ill be able to solve my problem but I want to know why my Checkbox isnt updating when I pass the setstate as a callback from a stateful widget.Im sorry if this question is dumb im just getting started with Flutter so any help is appreciated.

This is my stateless widget which builds the checkbox in a tile

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TaskTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final bool isChecked;
  final void Function(bool?) checkboxCallback;

  TaskTile({required this.title,required this.isChecked,required this.checkboxCallback});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(title,style: TextStyle(decoration: isChecked?TextDecoration.lineThrough:null),),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: checkboxCallback,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the stateful widget where I am giving the callback

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'task_tile.dart';
import 'task.dart';

class TaskList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TaskListState createState() => _TaskListState();
}

class _TaskListState extends State<TaskList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isChecked = false;

    List<Task> tasks = [
      Task(title: 'Buy Milk', isDone: isChecked),
      Task(title: 'Buy Bread', isDone: isChecked),
      Task(title: 'Buy Eggs', isDone: isChecked),
    ];

    return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return TaskTile(title: tasks[index].title,isChecked: tasks[index].isDone,checkboxCallback: (checkboxState){
        setState(() {
          tasks[index].toggleIsDone();
        });
      },);
    },itemCount: tasks.length,);
  }
}
```

Also this is the Task Class where I am giving the toggle function to change the state

```
class Task{
  final String title;
  bool isDone;

  Task({required this.title,required this.isDone});

  void toggleIsDone(){
    isDone = !isDone;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the function.
Instead of

```
trailing: Checkbox(
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: checkboxCallback,
      ),
```

Can you try

```
trailing: Checkbox(
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: (){checkboxCallback();},
      ),
```

Comment: I tried it  but then it shows 2 errors that argument type 'void Function()' cant be assigned to parameter type 'void Function(bool?)?' and 1 positional argument expected but 0 found so I added 'value' inside both round brackets and the errors went away but the checkbox still doesnt work

Comment: Can you change
 final void Function(bool?) checkboxCallback;
to
final Function checkboxCallback;

Comment: changed it still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `TaskTile` statefull. `TaskList` can be `StatelessWidget`.

Here is the answer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TaskList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isChecked = false;

    List<Task> tasks = [
      Task(title: 'Buy Milk', isDone: isChecked),
      Task(title: 'Buy Bread', isDone: isChecked),
      Task(title: 'Buy Eggs', isDone: isChecked),
    ];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return TaskTile(
          title: tasks[index].title,
          isChecked: tasks[index].isDone,
          checkboxCallback: (value) {
            tasks[index].toggleIsDone();
          },
        );
      },
      itemCount: tasks.length,
    );
  }
}

class TaskTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final bool isChecked;
  final Function checkboxCallback;

  TaskTile(
      {required this.title,
      required this.isChecked,
      required this.checkboxCallback,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TaskTileState createState() => _TaskTileState();
}

class _TaskTileState extends State<TaskTile> {
  late bool _isChecked;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isChecked = widget.isChecked;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        widget.title,
        style: TextStyle(
            decoration: _isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null),
      ),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        value: _isChecked,
        onChanged: (value) {
          widget.checkboxCallback(value);
          setState(() {
            _isChecked = value!;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Task {
  final String title;
  bool isDone;

  Task({required this.title, required this.isDone});

  void toggleIsDone() {
    isDone = !isDone;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this I was just hesistant of making my TaskTile stateful because the tutorial I've been following had the TaskList as stateful and was teaching how to use the callback function to set the state for a stateless widget and for them this code was working but for some reason mine wasn't. So if u have any idea why this doesn't work it will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, You are trying to change the state (isChanged) of the Task object in a list. This list inturn is used in listview builder. Since flutter work with immutable data and you are sending the reference of the list to the listview builder, the changes of the element in the list wont be reflected in the UI, eventhough you used setState function. Instead try creating a new list with the same name with the updated element. This will definitely work.

I got the idea from this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847327/11844877

PS
I am a newbie to flutter and don't mind if my answer wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For any `dynamic` change your `widget class` need to be `stateful`, if you are using `vscode` than you can easily change from stateless to `statful`   . First hover to your `statless` widget and than you will get a bulb like indicator , press it than you will get an option of changing the state.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution from the link below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class TaskList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isChecked = false;
    List<Task> tasks = [
      Task(title: 'Buy Milk', isDone: isChecked),
      Task(title: 'Buy Bread', isDone: isChecked),
      Task(title: 'Buy Eggs', isDone: isChecked),
    ];
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return TaskTile(
          title: tasks[index].title,
          isChecked: tasks[index].isDone,
          checkboxCallback: (value) {
            tasks[index].toggleIsDone();
          },
        );
      },
      itemCount: tasks.length,
    );
  }
}
class TaskTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final bool isChecked;
  final Function checkboxCallback;
  TaskTile(
      {required this.title,
      required this.isChecked,
      required this.checkboxCallback,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _TaskTileState createState() => _TaskTileState();
}
class _TaskTileState extends State<TaskTile> {
  late bool _isChecked;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isChecked = widget.isChecked;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        widget.title,
        style: TextStyle(
            decoration: _isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null),
      ),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        value: _isChecked,
        onChanged: (value) {
          widget.checkboxCallback(value);
          setState(() {
            _isChecked = value!;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
class Task {
  final String title;
  bool isDone;
  Task({required this.title, required this.isDone});
  void toggleIsDone() {
    isDone = !isDone;
  }
}
```

https://codeutility.org/why-is-my-checkbox-not-updating-when-i-pass-a-callback-from-a-stateful-widget-to-stateless-widget/

Answer (score 0):

tasks_tile.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TaskTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isChecked;
  final String TaskTitle;
  final Function(bool?) CheckboxCallback;

  TaskTile(
      {required this.isChecked,
      required this.TaskTitle,
      required this.CheckboxCallback});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        '$TaskTitle',
        style: TextStyle(
            decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null),
      ),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        activeColor: Colors.red.shade800,
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: CheckboxCallback,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

tasks_list.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todoey/widgets/tasks_tile.dart';
import 'package:todoey/models/task.dart';

class TasksList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Task> tasks;

  TasksList(this.tasks);

  @override
  State<TasksList> createState() => _TasksListState();
}

class _TasksListState extends State<TasksList> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return TaskTile(
          TaskTitle: widget.tasks[index].name,
          isChecked: widget.tasks[index].isDone,
          CheckboxCallback: (bool? checkBoxState) {
            setState(
              () {
                widget.tasks[index].toggleDone();
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
      itemCount: widget.tasks.length,
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the solution that worked for me by adding bool? inside the parenthesis 'final Function(bool?) checkboxCallback;' and in checkboxCallback in tasks_list.dart file add 'checkboxCallback: (bool? checkBoxState){},.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).